# FOREIGN KEY in CREATE NEW TABLE AS in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am following https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp to create new table AS and my task is to add foreign key into it. It fails and gives syntax error while I try to do it.

```
CREATE TABLE movie_genre AS 
SELECT movie.movie_id, movie.genres
FROM movie
FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie(movie_id);
```

There is no guide how to put it when using `AS`

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE TABLE [...] FROM` do not support any constraints/foreign keys.

But do not worry. You can issue follow up `ALTER TABLE` to add necessary constraints/foreign keys.

Comment: That's not true, you can add constraints as part of `CREATE ... AS SELECT ... FROM`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Source?

Comment: OK. So after new table name can follow definitions of columns, then followed select to source table. Neat.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to make this is to add foreign key afterwards.

```
CREATE TABLE movie_genre
 AS (SELECT movie.movie_id, movie.genres
    FROM movie
    );

ALTER TABLE movie_genre
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (movie_id)
    REFERENCES movie(movie_id);
```